# Naming of paragraph subsections

Tags: meaning

Regarding the questions: What do you call those divisions of a book bigger than a paragraph but smaller than a chapter?  Is not such a division best known as a PARICOPE from the Greek PARIKOPE or "a cutting around" as in the selection of a passage from the Bible in religious services?

Comment: This is really just an answer to the original question, and the answers here are either comments on it, or (rather missing the point) duplicates of older answers there.

Answer (score 0):

No: most English speakers will fail to understand the ecclesiastical term of art *pericope* even if you spell it correctly, and *[section](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/section)* (sense 2) is in everyday use for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Also [passage](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Passage) can convey the concept:

> (Literary & Literary Critical Terms) a section of a written work, speech, etc, esp one of moderate length.

Source:Collins English Dictionary

Comment: As a teacher of literature I generally use "passage" to mean a portion that I or a critic or a student might select for attention, but that is *not* deliberately demarcated from its context by the author or editor. "Section" applies whether it is typographically demarcated or not.

Answer (score 0):

LaTeX divides a Book into Chapters, a Chapter into Sections, a Section into SubSections, a SubSection into SubSubSections.

I think the notions propounded by LaTeX are representative of fairly modern thinking.

I am not sure whether a pericope corresponds to a Section, a SubSection, or a SubSubSection.